# Can the twin prime conjecture be stated in terms of ideals in a useful way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, integers, twin-primes, galois-connections

Let $\mathcal{I}^{\bullet}(\Bbb{Z})$ be the set of nonzero ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$.  It is a cancellative multiplicative monoid since $\Bbb{Z}$ is a PID.  Define $\mathcal{I}^{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\phi} \Bbb{Z} : n\Bbb{Z} \mapsto n$.  Then $\phi((n)(m)) = mn$ and $\phi((m) + (n)) = \gcd(m,n)$.  Thus at least $\phi$ is a multiplicative monoid hom.

The reason for looking at this map is that the twin prime conjecture addresses the generators and not the ideals they generate.  But this map links the two.

The inverse map $\psi : \Bbb{Z} \to \mathcal{I}^{\bullet} : n \to n \Bbb{Z}$.

The two maps together form an *antitone galois connection*, where the poset on $\mathcal{I}^{\bullet}$ is subset inclusion and the poset on $\Bbb{Z}$ is divisibility.  See [Pete L. Clark's CA book, pg. 32](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf).

Is this enough to make an ideal form of the twin prime conjecture?

Comment: It is easy enough to pick out the nonzero *prime* ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ since these are the maximal ideals.  However it is unclear how one might express the primality of $p+2$ (given prime $p$) in a natural way using the approach you outline.

Comment: @hardmath thanks

Comment: I don't follow what you wrote. You'd better ask if there is a generalization of the twin-prime conjecture in number fields. IMO the obvious one is "for any acceptable $c$ there are infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,\mathfrak{p}_2$ with $N(\mathfrak{p}_2) =N(\mathfrak{p}_1)+c$".

Comment: @reuns I don't understand AlgNT yet, so I have to KISS

Comment: $\mathfrak{p}=(4+i)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with ideal norm $N(\mathfrak{p}) = \# \ \ \mathbb{Z}/(4+i) = 17$

Comment: @reuns, that's intriguing.  I have to study my CA book first though, but it does go into some AlgNT.

Comment: See [there](http://math.tufts.edu/faculty/rlemkeoliver/papers/11-BoundedGaps.pdf) the generalization in number fields is slightly different

Comment: For what it's worth: I don't see any useful relationship between ideal theory and the twin prime conjecture.  (To generalize the conjecture to other settings one might want to state it in terms of ideals.  That's not the same thing.)